# MultiDimensional Array with Foreach

Tags: php, html, multidimensional-array, foreach

My array

```
<?php
$aLaptop = array (
'Acer' => array (
    'img' => 'Images/Acer.jpg',
    'Price' => '699,99',
    ),

'Dell' => array (
    'img' => 'Images/Dell.jpg',
    'Price' => '699,99',
    )
);  



?>
```

and

my foreach

```
<?php
    foreach($aLaptop as $sMerk => $aModel)
    {
        echo '<h2>'.$sMerk.'</h2><br />';
        echo '<br />';
        foreach($aModel as $sInfo => $sExtra )
        {
            echo '<img src="'.$sExtra.'"<br />';
            echo '<h3>'.$sExtra.'</h3><br />';
            echo '<br />';
        }
    }   

    ?>
```

But this isn't working can someone please help?
I would like to be able t have the picture and the price.
Now I get the picture, the picture path, an unfound picture and the price.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
foreach($aLaptop as $sMerk => $aModel)
{
    echo '<h2>'.$sMerk.'</h2><br />';
    echo '<br />';
    echo '<img src="'.$aModel['img'].'"><br />';
    echo '<h3>'.$aModel['Price'].'</h3><br />';
    echo '<br />';
}
```